# SQL Server Stored Procedure not Executing another SP

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server stored procedure, however when it executes it does not seem to execute the other stored procedure I wish to call.

Here is my stored procedure example, you can see my `EXEC` statement.

If anyone can see why this wouldn't work then please let me know! Thanks

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddField]
   @tablename nvarchar(20),
   @newfield nvarchar(20),
   @datatype nvarchar(20),
   @length nvarchar(20),
   @displayname nvarchar(20),
   @tableseq nvarchar(20),
   @varcharmax nvarchar(20),
   @SEQ_PARENT nvarchar(20),
   @FK_MODULE_VIEW nvarchar(20),
   @FK_MODULE_VAL nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @p_tablename varchar(20), 
        @type varchar(20), 
        @FK_SQL_DATA nvarchar(max), 
        @FK_TABLE_NAME varchar(20), 
        @ALTER_TABLE_SQL nvarchar(max),
        @ALTER_TABLE_SQL_ADD_FK nvarchar(max),
        @FIELD_REF_SQL_DATA nvarchar(max)

    SELECT @p_tablename = TABLENAME FROM SD_TABLES WHERE VIEWNAME = @tablename

    SET @type = @datatype + @length

    if @datatype = 'TEST1'
    BEGIN
    --SQL HERE
    END

    if @datatype = 'TEST2'
    BEGIN
    --SQL HERE      
    END

    if @datatype = 'TEST3'
    BEGIN
    --SQL HERE
    END

    EXEC SD_CreateAllViewStatements
END
```

Comment: What does SD_CreateAllViewStatements do? Have you tried putting some debug code / a print line in it to see if it does get called?

Comment: Just checking - In the real script, are there `BEGIN` statements for each of those `if` statements as well as the `END` statements.

Comment: Sorry, yes there are BEGIN statements.

Comment: the SD_CreateAllViewStatements works absolutely fine if I execute it manually. I think there may be a timing issue as the actual SP above needs to be completed BEFORE it can run the SD_CreateAllViewStatements  otherwise it will fail

Answer (score 0):

I can think about 2 scenarios why this can happened:

1. The main script crashing before the `SD_CreateAllViewStatements` is called. You can add the simple `try ... catch` construction to avoid the SP `AddField` crashing.
2. There's a `return` statement in your `if ... begin ... end blocks` which need to be removed (or the SP `AddField` need to be redesigned)

In both cases the script basically is not execution the call to the `SD_CreateAllViewStatements`. In all other cases the SP `SD_CreateAllViewStatements` must be executed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The last line of each of my IF statements do the following: EXEC sp_executesql @FIELD_REF_SQL_DATA. What is odd is the SD_CreateAllViewStatements does seem to get executed because it basically drops a view and re-creates. The view get dropped but not recreated. If I manually execute the SD_CreateAllViewStatements manually it then recreates the VIEW fine. My main Stored Procedure above makes some table changes which is why the view statement gets recreated.

Comment: OK, Ignore this question. It works fine if I execute the main Stored Procedure from the database. If I use my application it fails to finish executing the SD_CreateAllViewStatements

Comment: In this case the issue can be the timeout - in case of the code is "heavy". Default timeout is set to 30 sec. Check how much time the SP is running from Management Studio and what is the timeout setting in your application.